# How to compare each elements in an Array and group the ones that have same data (in my case date) ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, indexing

```
const patientDetails = [
 {patientName: "A", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room1", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "B", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room8", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "C", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room2", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "D", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room5", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "E", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room6", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "F", dateReg: "2019-11-11", room: "room10", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "G", dateReg: "2019-11-11", room: "room18", user: "k" }
]
```

I've got an array which has patient details. What I want to do is, if the dateReg of the patient in the is the same then I would like to basically group them. 
In the UI, I would like to render a row with the date first(2019-11-12) then the next rows would be filled with the paitent details that have the same date(2019-11-12) until there is another patient with a different date (2019-11-11). If there is a different date and I would want to add a new row with the new date (2019-11-11) then render the patient details that have those date (2019-11-11) until a different date and so on...

I can't get it work and not entirely sure if I'm in the right direction.

i've tried

```
const dateCheck = patientDetails[0].dateReg; 

date.map(patient => {
  if(patient.dateReg === dateCheck){
    return (

        <tr>
          <td>{patient.dateReg}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{paitent.patientName} </td>
          <td>{patient.room}</td>
          <td>{patient.user}</td>
        <tr>

    )
  }else {
    return(
     <tr>
          <td>{patient.dateReg}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{paitent.patientName} </td>
          <td>{patient.room}</td>
          <td>{patient.user}</td>
        <tr>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach to grouping array data revolves around using `array.prototype.reduce`. You can use `array.prototype.sort`. Here's the essence of it without a UI:

```js
const patientDetails = [
 {patientName: "A", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room1", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "B", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room8", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "C", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room2", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "D", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room5", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "E", dateReg: "2019-11-12", room: "room6", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "F", dateReg: "2019-11-11", room: "room10", user: "k" },
 {patientName: "G", dateReg: "2019-11-11", room: "room18", user: "k" }
];

let grouped = patientDetails.reduce((g, d) => {
  g[d.dateReg] = g[d.dateReg] || [];
  g[d.dateReg].push(d);
  return g;
}, {});

let sorted = Object.values(grouped).sort(([a], [b]) => a.dateReg > b.dateReg);

sorted.forEach(s => {
  console.log(`===${s[0].dateReg}===`);
  s.forEach(ss => console.log(`${ss.patientName} ${ss.room} ${ss.user}`));
  console.log();
});
```

Comment: If you use Map instead of an object literal then there is no need to sort as it'll produce the groups in the order they were given. Not sure if the order they were given is important but if it is then sort may not produce the desired output.

Comment: We want the output sorted by date, and input may not be, so `sort` is still required.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that would indicate that. Since you are comparing strings you should do `b.dateReg.localeCompare(a.dateReg)`

Comment: @HMR are you able to explain the reduce bit please? It works thank you but I don't understand how you have utilised reduce in this instance. 

let grouped = patientDetails.reduce((g, d) => {
  g[d.dateReg] = g[d.dateReg] || [];
  g[d.dateReg].push(d);
  return g;
}, {});

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following will give you an idea how to group the data (called grouped). Here I only console.log it but you can create jsx out of it in one with one map

```js
const patientDetails = [
  {patientName: 'A',dateReg: '2019-11-12',room: 'room1',user: 'k',},
  {patientName: 'B',dateReg: '2019-11-12',room: 'room8',user: 'k',},
  {patientName: 'C',dateReg: '2019-11-12',room: 'room2',user: 'k',},
  {patientName: 'D',dateReg: '2019-11-12',room: 'room5',user: 'k',},
  {patientName: 'E',dateReg: '2019-11-12',room: 'room6',user: 'k',},
  {patientName: 'F',dateReg: '2019-11-11',room: 'room10',user: 'k',},
  {patientName: 'G',dateReg: '2019-11-11',room: 'room18',user: 'k',},
];
const grouped = [
  ...patientDetails
    .reduce(
      (result, patient) =>
        result.set(
          patient.dateReg,
          (result.get(patient.dateReg) || []).concat(
            patient
          )
        ),
      new Map()
    )
    .entries(),
]//.sort(([a],[b])=>b.localeCompare(a));//if you need sorting
console.log(
  grouped
    .map(
      ([date, patients]) => `${date}
  ${patients
    .map(({ patientName }) => patientName)
    .join('\n  ')}`
    )
    .join('\n')
);
```

Comment: Hi, say if all my patients are A and I still want to group by date. In that case, will this work?

Comment: @Jereme Yes, it only groups by date.